# Custom network message from router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Is there a way for a wireless router to send custom messages to a device on the network at regular intervals? Perhaps there is a setting that I can use that will allow me to display a message to all devices connected to my network when they view network information or something like this. I am aware that some routers have beacon features. Is there a way to add a limited amount of custom information to the beacon?

I would like to do this through my wireless router. I have not yet purchased the router so first I want to know if such a thing is possible

Comment: Which OSes are the clients running? Are you trying to actually **push a message to clients** (ex: avahi/bonjour, Windows Messenger service, linux wall command, etc.)? Or simply **display a [welcome/login](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Chillispot) webpage** for clients (similar to many public hotspots)? Please clarify. As far as purchasing goes, any router with *DD-WRT firmware* will allow you do some crazy and wonderful things :)

Comment: By "beacon features", do you mean beacon frames? Beacon frames are sent automatically by all wireless routers several times per second to synchronize wireless clients - they're not a way of displaying messages.

Comment: @justbrowsing
I do not want to display a welcome/login page. What I want is for some additional small bit of information to be appended to the beacon.

Comment: @Huskehn So I see on wikipedia that the beacon is composed of the timestamp as well as two other components. Do either of you guys know if there a way to add anything to the beacon such as the time in which each frame was sent?

Comment: @jizcoBorneo The only thing that an actual user can see in a beacon frame is the SSID. The rest of the frame is used by the actual wireless hardware.

Comment: If you want to [hide data in a beacon frame](http://revision3.com/haktip/beacons) (ala SMS in a GSM beacon) that's fine but clients will need to run software such as `wireshark` to read it. Additionally un-associated "clients" in *monitor mode* may be able to intercept and decrypt those packets.

Comment: @justbrowsing
Does this work for multi router networks? For example say my home is bigger than most so I have 3 wireless routers

Comment: @Huskehn Ok suppose I am not interested in direct messaging. I just want to be able to store a custom string onto the router that can be accessed by other devices that are connected to the network. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I previously used a router - a Netgear from Sky in the UK - which I was able to setup to email me a log every morning at 07:00.  Would this meet your requirement ?

Comment: This seems close but I do not want an email. What I want is a message that is transmitted via the radio signal of the wifi so that connection to a network is not required